# View and indexing

Tags: couchbase

Is indexing via view with respect to an inner property of inner object inside a document is more expensive of a property of  the document itself.

Say for example if have a document A as follows:

```
{
   "person": 
   {
      "id":1234345,
      "name":"eyal"
   },
   //... more properties of document A 
}
```

and I want to run a view according to id of person.
Does it more expensive (the indexing etc) than the following document:

```
{

      "id":1234345,
      "name":"eyal",
      //... more properties of document A 
}
```

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, There are not speed differences between the two methods.